# Error when logging in Ionic 3 + Angular 4 + Firebase mobile application - Error: username is not defined

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to create a simple chat application with  Ionic 3 and Firebase. Registering and logging in users works.

Users give their username in login.html and I'd like to use this username later on the chat.html page. This is the next page coming up after logging in. I'm using ionic storage to get and set the username (email address). I can't see the username from the chat page.

When trying ionic serve, I get this log on console: 
ionViewDidLoad ChatPage

There is a space after ChatPage, that's the initial value of username. I'd like it to change to the current logged in user's username. I'm trying to get this value in ionViewDidLoad() in chat.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
})
export class ChatPage {

  username: string= '';
  message: string= '';

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage) {
    this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {
      if (val != null) {
        this.username= val;
      }
    });
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.db.list('/chat').push({
      username: this.username,
      message: this.message
    })
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let username= '';

    this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {
      if (val != null) {
        username= val;
      }
    });
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChatPage', username);
  }
}
```

login.html:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Login
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <div padding>
    <button ion-button (click)="signInUser()">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

login.ts:

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, AlertController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { ChatPage } from '../chat/chat';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})

export class LoginPage {
  username: string= '';
  password: string= '';

  constructor(private fire: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, private alertCtrl: AlertController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage)
  {
    this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {
      if (val != null) {
        this.username= val;
      }
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  alert(message: string) {
    this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Info!',
      subTitle: message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    }).present();
  }

  signInUser() {
    this.storage.set('username', this.username);
    this.fire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.username, this.password).then(data=> {
    console.log('got data', this.fire.auth.currentUser);
    this.alert('Success! You\'re logged in');
    this.navCtrl.push(ChatPage);

    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('got an error', error);
      this.alert(error.message);
    })
    console.log('Would sign in with ', this.username, this.password)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first two lines in signInUser function.

```
signInUser() {

    this.fire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.username, this.password).then(data=> {
    console.log('got data', this.fire.auth.currentUser);
    this.alert('Success! You\'re logged in');
    this.navCtrl.push(ChatPage);

    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('got an error', error);
      this.alert(error.message);
    })
    console.log('Would sign in with ', this.username, this.password)
}
```

To use the username in other pages store it in the localstorage using [ionic storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)

Comment: Thank you! I don't get the error any more, but I think I'm doing something wrong, because I can't see the username from the chat page (I included the modifications in my original question)